# Couchdb, return number of Docs

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-python

How do I do this simple thing, I just want the number of documents in a database. So far I am using a loop function in python to do this, but it seems an incredible inefficient way of doing this. Fauton tells you at the bottom of the page how many docs there are, how can i get this number in either python or javascript please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant API call is [`GET /{db}`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#get--db). In the python driver, it is [`db.info()`](https://couchdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.info).

Comment: Couldn't get "GET" statement to work, but the python one works a treat, which is perfect, thank you.

Comment: It's not a "statement", it's an HTTP request.

Answer (score 5):

When you send a GET request to the database root, as per OrangeDog's answer, i.e.: `GET http://couchdb.server.com/mydatabase` you will get a JSON back, looking similar to the following:

```
{
 "db_name":"mydatabase",
 "update_seq":"2786-g1AAAAFreJzLYWBg4MhgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUoxJTIkyf___z8riYGB0RuPuiQFIJlkD1Naik-pA0hpPExpDj6lCSCl9TClwXiU5rEASYYGIAVUPR-sPJqg8gUQ5fvBygMIKj8AUX4frDyOoPIHEOUQt0dlAQB32XIg",
 "sizes":{
    "file":13407816,
    "external":3760750,
    "active":4059261
 },
 "purge_seq":0,
 "other": {
    "data_size":3760750
 },
 "doc_del_count":0,
 "doc_count":2786,
 "disk_size":13407816,
 "disk_format_version":6,
 "data_size":4059261,
 "compact_running":false,
 "instance_start_time":"0"
}
```

The field `doc_count` is a count of all documents in the database. Bear in mind that the count includes design documents, that might not be what you are looking for.

There are other options, like creating a view with a default reduce function `_count` that would allow you to get a single number representing a number of documents generated in that view, that could get around the issue of counting in design documents.